# Paginate link with hash parameter with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, kaminari

I am using kaminari to paginate the results in my view. The url is /tracks and I use this code in the view to create the pagination:

```
<%= paginate @tracks %>
```

The problem is that the paginated content is inside a bootstrap tab, witch is activated when the user accesses the link with the hash parameter:

```
/tracks#items
```

Is there any way to have the pagination link be something like:

`/tracks?page=X#items`

so the tab is automatically enabled when the user clicks the page link?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the anchor to the pagination links like this:

```
<%= paginate @tracks, :params => { :anchor => 'items' } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write this code:

```
<%= paginate @tracks, :params => { :anchor => 'items' } %>
```

after ruby 1.9 is:

```
<%= paginate @tracks, params: { anchor: 'items' } %>
```